# Yocto: remove packageconfig item

Tags: qt, qt5, yocto, bitbake

In a recipe (`meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qttools_git.bb`) I found:

```
PACKAGECONFIG ??= ""
PACKAGECONFIG[qtwebkit] = ",,qtwebkit"
```

now, under my own `meta-custom-layer` I'm going to create the same path and add a `.bbappend` file: `meta-custom-layer/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qttools_git.bbappend`.

I want to remove the second line, because I'm not interested in `qtwebkit`.
It would be enough to put:

```
PACKAGECONFIG[qtwebkit] = ""
```

or I need something else? 
Because there is the `??=` operator, I guess the `PACKAGECONFIG` variable is updated with `qtwebkit` elsewhere. I need to find and remove also that assignement? Is there a quick way to find out where is appended?

### UPDATE

To find where the `qtwebkit` is configured I tried to use grep:

```
$ grep -nrw . -e qtwebkit
./layers/meta-st/meta-st-openstlinux/recipes-samples/packagegroups/packagegroup-framework-sample-qt-extra.bb:30:    qtwebkit                    \
./layers/meta-st/meta-st-openstlinux/recipes-samples/packagegroups/packagegroup-framework-sample-qt-extra.bb:53:    qtwebkit-examples           \
Binary file ./layers/meta-qt5/.git/index matches
./layers/meta-qt5/README.md:8:When building stuff like `qtdeclarative`, `qtquick`, `qtwebkit`, make
./layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/packagegroups/packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target.bb:12:    ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'opengl', 'qtwebkit-dev', '', d)} \
./layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qttools/0001-add-noqtwebkit-configuration.patch:25:     BROWSER = qtwebkit
./layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qttools/0001-add-noqtwebkit-configuration.patch:32:-equals(BROWSER, "qtwebkit") {
./layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qttools/0001-add-noqtwebkit-configuration.patch:33:+equals(BROWSER, "qtwebkit"):!contains(CONFIG, noqtwebkit) {
./layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qttools_git.bb:28:PACKAGECONFIG[qtwebkit] = ",,qtwebkit"
./layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qttools_git.bb:32:    ${@bb.utils.contains('PACKAGECONFIG', 'qtwebkit', '', 'CONFIG+=noqtwebkit', d)} \
./layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qt5-creator_git.bb:17:DEPENDS = "qtbase qtscript qtwebkit qtxmlpatterns qtx11extras qtdeclarative qttools qttools-native qtsvg chrpath-replacement-native"
./layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtbase_git.bb:76:# This is in qt5.inc, because qtwebkit-examples are using it to enable ca-certificates dependency
./layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtwebkit-examples_git.bb:18:DEPENDS += "qtwebkit qtxmlpatterns"
./layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtwebkit-examples_git.bb:19:RDEPENDS_${PN}-examples += "qtwebkit-qmlplugins"
./layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtwebkit_git.bb:12:# Patches from https://github.com/meta-qt5/qtwebkit/commits/b5.11
./layers/meta-qt5/lib/recipetool/create_qt5.py:101:              'webkit': 'qtwebkit',
./layers/meta-qt5/lib/recipetool/create_qt5.py:102:              'webkitwidgets': 'qtwebkit',
```

So I think the line to remove is the one I described above.
`bitbake -e <image>` leads to an output so long that overflows the console buffer... I tried to grep the output looking for `qtwebkit` but nothing is returned.

The same applies for `grep -nrw . -e DISTRO_FEATURES | grep qtwebkit`.

Comment: Have you tried removing qtwebkit from `DISTRO_FEATURES`?

Comment: Have you tried `bitbake -e` (or `bitbake -e <your image>`) and reviewing the environment to what is adding `qtwebkit` to `PACKAGECONFIG_pn-qttools` (guessing on that one)?

Comment: Question updated!

Answer (score 3):

The `PACKAGECONFIG[qtwebkit] = ",,qtwebkit"` line is showing what enabling or disabling that feature would do if `qtwebkit` exists in that package's `PACKAGECONFIG` variable ([see here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-PACKAGECONFIG)).  Based on that second line and the documentation, it's doing "nothing" in either case.

More towards your question about how to diagnose something like, "why is this variable set," a starting point is to use `bitbake -e [optional package or image name] > env.log` to dump the environment to a log file that you can review.  It would be worth checking this with no package or image name as well as with the package and whatever image you're trying to build (sometimes the image configuration might enable a feature in another package's `PACKAGECONFIG` via other variables; checking the environment will often show you why something was set).